# How to select a range of elements in repeated pattern

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say there are 12 items in 4 rows.

```
 |  1   ||  2   ||  3   |
 |  4   ||  5   ||  6   |
 |  7   ||  8   ||  9   |
 |  10  ||  11  ||  12  |
```

I want to select and style 2nd row and 4th row, How do I do that?

Note that rows are not in different HTML elements, in fact they are all an ul li element.

Desired Result:

```
 |  1   ||  2   ||  3   |
 |--4---||--5---||--6---|
 |  7   ||  8   ||  9   |
 |--10--||--11--||--12--|
```

I have tried playing with this:

```
li:nth-child(n+4)
```

It selects all the elements after first three.
Then I tried this:

```
li:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+8)
```

This only selects 4, 5 & 6 but I cant repeat this pattern to select 10, 11 & 12 as well. Is there any solution for this in CSS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a commonly-asked question, but I wanted to point out that the reason `:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+6)` only matches one specific range of elements is that it only provides a single start point (n+4) and a single end point (-n+6). The only elements that can be greater than or equal to 4 *and* less than or equal to 6 are 4, 5 and 6, so it's impossible to match elements outside of this range using the same selector. Adding more `:nth-child()` pseudos will only narrow down the matches.

The solution is to think of this in terms of columns, assuming there will always be exactly 3 columns (elements) per row. You have three columns, so you will need three *separate* `:nth-child()` pseudos. Elements 4 and 10 from the first column are 6 elements apart, so the argument to all of the `:nth-child()` pseudos needs to start with 6n.

The +b portion in the An+B expression can either be +4, +5 and +6, or 0, -1 and -2 — they will both match the same set of elements:

- `li:nth-child(6n+4), li:nth-child(6n+5), li:nth-child(6n+6)`
- `li:nth-child(6n), li:nth-child(6n-1), li:nth-child(6n-2)`

You cannot do this with a single `:nth-child()` pseudo-class, or a single compound selector consisting of any combination of `:nth-child()` pseudos, because the An+B notation simply doesn't allow such expressions to be constructed that match elements in ranges as described.

Comment: Dam!! it was so simple (cheers), [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld0cgoxn/) just in case someone want's to play with this.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this with a single selector and need to use a grouping of `nth-child` selectors like in the below snippet:

```css
li:nth-child(6n), li:nth-child(6n-1), li:nth-child(6n-2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

**Selector Explanation:**

- `li:nth-child(6n)` - Selects the 6th (=6*1), 12th (=6*2), 18th (=6*3) elements and so on.
- `li:nth-child(6n-1)` - Selects the 5th (=(6*1)-1), 11th (=(6*2)-1), 17th (=(6*3)-1) elements and so on.
- `li:nth-child(6n-2)` - Selects the 4th (=(6*1)-2), 10th (=(6*2)-2), 16th (=(6*3)-2) elements and so on.

**Note:** Generally `n` starts from 0 but I have excluded it in the explanation because we don't have any 0th, -1th or -2nd element.