# Target repeating group of elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can a single `nth-child()` selector be constructed to target a repeating group of elements, such as every 4th through 7th in a list?

For example, how can I select all "b" elements?

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```
:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+7) {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

Except it doesn't repeat ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9zpr0ebz/2/)).

I know that multiple selectors can be used:

```
:nth-child(7n+4),
:nth-child(7n+5),
:nth-child(7n+6),
:nth-child(7n+7) {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

This works. But I'm wondering if there's a single selector that can be chained together (CSS only).

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9zpr0ebz/2/)

Comment: I was expecting a self-answered question. Hopes dashed :(

Comment: Nevertheless, does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623568/how-to-select-a-range-of-elements-in-repeated-pattern) answer your question?