# How to achieve CSS3 irregular selector :nth-child() pattern [1 3 4 6 7 9...]

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, css-selectors, grid

I want to apply css on 3x3 grid as follows
the first and last cards in the grid follows a `margin-top: -195px`.

[image: Grid]

Here's what I have tried till now:

https://jsfiddle.net/7wv8tLdz/

I am using bootstrap, I achieved this using multiple rows, but it leaves a gap on `col-md-6` because of odd number of elements.

The catch is I need to make it in a single row so that all cards could align in each column in serial order.

In short, while selecting elements I have to follow the pattern 1 3 4 6 7 9 ...

How can I achieve this pattern of selection in css3 `:nth-child()` and using just single row?

Comment: What do you want to select them for? (maybe there's a better way of doing things) And why are you using negative top margins?

Comment: @WebDevBooster Want to follow the design spec precisely, kindly suggest better way if you have in mind. (I can use positive margins on 2,5,8,11.. card otherwise)

Comment: You haven't answered my question. What do you want to do with the selection? What is the selection for?

Comment: By selection i meant the nth-child() selection in the pattern that follows the css of `margin-top: -195px` (if using 1,3,4,6,7,9..th childs) or otherwise `margin-top: 195px` (if using of 2,5,8...th child)

Comment: Aha, so the selection is supposed to be for applying margins. And what happens if the screen gets smaller so that only 2 columns fit in?

Comment: Yes, in case of medium it'll become 2 col layout, and in small, it'll become 1 column layout.
The problem is only with 2 col. layout due to the unnecessary gap, check the fiddle to understand better

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the following pattern by using 2 `nth-child()` selectors:

```
&:nth-child(3n+1),
&:nth-child(3n) {
    .post {
        margin-top: -195px;
    }
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7wv8tLdz/2/

on iterating, it's following the pattern of 1 3 4 6 7 9… and solves the 2 column layout gap problem

Comment: As you've seen, the key is to break it down into *subpatterns* that you can recognize, and realize that it's possible if you're willing to use more than one :nth-child() selector. See [another example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623568/how-to-select-a-range-of-elements-in-repeated-pattern/32623708#32623708).