# CSS table style for rows 1 and 2, then another style for 3 and 4 and repeat, two styles in total

Tags: css

I have been trying unsuccessfully to define a CSS table style using tr:nth-child to define:

Row 1 - Blue

Row 2 - Blue

Row 3 - White

Row 4 - White

...and repeat

But I have failed! Can anyone put me out of my misery?

Thank you in advance...

The HTML is being generated by Powershell convertto-html, that generates something like:

```
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".\table.css" />
</head><body>
<p style="text-align:center;"><H2>Header</H2>
<table>
<tr><th>Count</th><th>Name</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Gary</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Sarah</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>Bob</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>Ian</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>Susan</td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>Robin</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>Paul</td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td>Jane</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you please post a “minimal, complete, and verifiable” example?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/32623568/8620333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
   tr {
    background: white;
}

tr:nth-child(4n+1) {
    background: blue;
}

tr:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background: blue;
}
```

```css
tr {
    background: white;
}

tr:nth-child(4n+1) {
    background: blue;
}

tr:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, this looks good here but when applying it to my table it starts at row 2, rather than the first row?

Comment: Did you use thead for table head?

Answer (score 0):

The following selectors will achieve what you're looking for:

```css
tr {
  background: blue;
}

tr:nth-child(4n),
tr:nth-child(4n-1) {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
</table>
```