# Add background color on every 3 list items after 3 list items

Tags: html, css

I have designed list using CSS flex and width I want to apply background colors in on every 3 list items after 3 list item. but i want to show colors in 2 pairs. I have tried using CSS Pseudo Class :nth-child() not get's design.

Note: I created design in pure HTML & CSS

```
 |  1   ||  2   ||  3   | 
 |--4---||--5---||--6---|  --- Green Background Color
 |  7   ||  8   ||  9   |
 |--10--||--11--||--12--|  --- Red Background Color
 |  13  ||  14  ||  15  |
 |--16--||--17--||--18--|  --- Green Background Color
 |  19  ||  20  ||  21  |
```

Comment: Show your code and we will help you.

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32623568/8620333

Comment: Yes, It's working on single colors but I want to add multiple colors.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS 3 nth-child

```
table tr:nth-child(3n+3) td {
  background: green;
}
```

Demo :

```css
table tr:nth-child(3n+3) td {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
 

   

<table>
    <tr><td>Table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You have added background color on every 3rd list items. It's not work for me please check question again. I have updated and enhanced problem clarity.